# Change of volume mixing dry & wet ingredients

Tags: alcohol

4C Water ~ 4 C Sugar ~ 1C instant Coffee[dry]  1QT Vodka

Water & dry ingredients mixed-simmered & cooled prior to adding Vodka.  Need to know volume as must let sit 30 days in glass vessel & stirred/swirled daily.

Would like to know amount volume of output

Comment: C is for ? cup ? 1QT ? quart ? what kind of recipe is this ?

Comment: With respect to my fellow responders...This is why we don't do recipe requests...why are we questioning this poster's recipe?  It's not what she came here for.  Did I misread the question?

Comment: @moscafj - I agree to some extent. Some of these comments seem a bit off-topic, or at least not expressed politely. Note that the simmer is likely here to dissolve the sugar and coffee easily, a common procedure in making simple syrup with a high-sugar percentage; it has nothing to do with brewing the coffee. I do, however, think it's useful to point out that there doesn't seem to be any benefit to letting this recipe sit/swirl for a month; any "extraction" of flavor from instant coffee would be done quickly and flavors would likely settle/meld within a few hours at most.

Comment: Disagree with the close vote; I feel the question as it stands is clear (how much will the resulting volume of mixing these items be).

Answer (score 3):

[This question helps,](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27350/for-equal-volumes-water-and-sugar-what-is-the-ratio-of-separated-volume-vs-com) from it, we learn that 1/2 cup table sugar + 1/2 cup water results in a volume of 3/4 cup.  The second answer claims that 2 cups of sugar + 2 cups of water equals a total volume of 3 and 1/8 cup.  Slightly different from the first response, but in the ball park.  I will assume that the combination of instant coffee and water leads to a similar result.  Therefore...I would calculate:

4 cups water + 4 cups sugar = 6 1/4 cups.

6 1/4 cups + 1 cup instant coffee = 6 3/4 cups (Same assumption as addition of sugar).

6 3/4 cups + 4 cups (1 QT) vodka = 10 3/4 cups.

Total volume = 10 3/4 cups or 2.69 quarts...or a bit more than half a gallon.

Feel free to correct my assumptions or math.