# How much liquid jaggery equals 1 cup jaggery powder?

Tags: measurements, brownies

I have liquid jaggery and I want to know how much to use if I need 1 cup of jaggery powder for a recipe

Answer (score 1):

Liquid Jaggery is not a terribly common ingredient, and I couldn't find any conversions for it ... but I could for a close relative, cane syrup to granulated sugar.  [This recipe](https://www.ehow.com/how_7159910_substitute-sugar-pure-cane-syrup.html) claims that cane syrup is equivalent to a 2:1 mixture of granulated sugar to water by volume.

So, reversing that, and using [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27350/for-equal-volumes-water-and-sugar-what-is-the-ratio-of-separated-volume-vs-com) to find that sugar dissolved in water retains about 60% of its volume (and vice versa), 1 1/4 to 1 1/3 cup of liquid jaggery should be about equivalent to 1 cup of crystals.  Also, you should reduce the other liquid in the recipe by 1/2 cup.